# "The cryptographic key was not found" in lotus notes MIME mail secnd

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

I am sending a mail in MIME format from lotusscript scheduled agent. Its throwing the below error. In am in a workaround. Please suggest me any already know ideas. It will be helpful for me.

```
Notes error: The cryptographic key was not found
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

**Found solution:**

This will happen when giving the mail send parameter as true.

Call mailDoc.send(False)  will work. before I passed as true.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/e9d956be9292df8b85256fc800669ab3?OpenDocument

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/37bdc0d7c19d817b8525777c0046b9e5?OpenDocument

Comment: Needs more information. Like sample code.

Comment: You should add your solution as an Answer, not an edit. That way you can mark the question answered.